# after 2nd update of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS no wlan0 again

Tags: 12.04, wireless, updates, dell, atheros

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kernel 3.5.0-49-generic) with **qualcomm atheros qca9565**

The first time, I did update and all the connections with the internet were lost.

Step by step, I restored the wired connection and then the wireless one. Yesterday I got a message to update due to an error, so after the second update, I lost the wireless connection : there is no `wlan0` anymore, only `eth0` and `lo`.

Ii can see all the parts of atheros card but I can't get to install it. I downloaded drivers and I tried to install them but without success.

I have read almost anything here and elsewhere about how to retrieve this and that but nothing worked.

I am new to Ubuntu. I need to restore my wireless connectivity. If possible, write me detailed instructions.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @Wild http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7532134/   hi human,i ran the script and got the info, thank you for your interest and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's install the backported driver and see if that fixes your wifi connection but first remove any drivers you installed yourself.

Go here [backport driver](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) and download the newest driver to your computer then place the file on your desktop and right click and extract here.

Then do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k 
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

When there is an update to the kernel you will have to do the following.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k 
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Comment: Thank you man for your help,I think I do not have any installed drivers but I am not sure.I will search it before.I have tried several but not this one.Let you know soon.

Comment: Please do and if it works accept the answer so everyone will benefit from your experience. Thanks

Comment: I did it exactly and it worked great! I only had to run "rfkill unblock all" to switch it on. So, after the next update I will run the other part also ;-) Thank you very much for your help!