# TP-LINK TL-WN751ND not detecting networks (most of the time)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 14.04, pci

I have the TP-LINK TL-WN751ND. I only bought it and fitted it in the last week. However, it has been causing a lot of issues. Before I bought this PCI card, I researched online to see if it was compatible with Ubuntu. I saw a lot of reports of it causing older versions (with older kernels) to freeze after a few minutes of operation, but I also saw a lot of those reports which also said this problem was fixed in a version of Ubuntu much older than 14.04 (around 12.04 if I recall). I also saw reports that this card works perfectly in 12.10. So I thought it would be fine, considering the amount of people reporting it works perfectly.

At first, I thought it had worked, it connected straight away with no problems, but after a while it began to disconnect itself after a few minutes of usage, and once it had disconnected itself you could not re-connect because the amount of networks available in the menu had drastically dropped from around 5 or 6, to just 2. Unfortunately, my router was not one of those 2. And from then on, the majority of the time it was only those 2 that would show up. And sometimes it was just 1. Sometimes, though, my router would show up, and it would connect just fine. However, after a few minutes of usage we end up back to square one.

I've looked around a lot, tried various solutions to do with the this card and similar and none of them seem to have worked. Before I go and buy a different card, I want to see if a bespoke question might get some answers. This is actually the second card I have tried now too.

Here are some generic points of interest related to the problem:

- The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
- The card is a TP-LINK TL-WN751ND.
- The chipset is a AR9227.
- The card is near-on brand new, and is the second card I have tried with Ubuntu.

Also, on a side note, does anybody know of any PCI (not PCI-E, or USB) wifi cards that are known to work without a hitch on Ubuntu?

Regards

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7723547/

Comment: Have you tried any driver parameters? What country are you in so we can see if your router is set to the right one.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure. Networking is not my forte. Anyway, I am in the UK. The router at hand is a new Sky router (link: http://www.sky.com/products/kit/sky-hub/).

Comment: Your router setting is for China, so I guess we need to change it to the UK.

Comment: Ok, odd. I'm not entirely sure how to change that.

Comment: I know how, I will post in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

We are changing the country code first, do:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^REG.*=$/&UK/' /etc/default/crda
```

Then do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

In the router set your encryption to WPA2 not mixed mode.
Change the channel to 1 or 11 they usually work best.
Save the router configuration, then reboot router and computer and unplug wired connection.

Set your wireless settings in network manager to match the screenshots.[image: DNS Settings][image: IPV6 Setting] Then reboot.

Comment: Hi, all commands executed without a hitch, however the problem persists. Can't see my router or any of the others I could see in the beginning.

Comment: Run the script again and post the new info file so we can see the changes. Run this command `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` and post the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok: wireless-info.txt: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7725202/ and ath9k.conf: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7725204/

Comment: Also, I'd like to add, the amount of networks increased this morning, and I managed to connect. I had good signal, but is disconnected itself after 10 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not having any issues with your router? The country code did not save so we will do it manually. `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` above the exit0 add this line `iw reg set GB` Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot. Is this the network you want to connect too SKYA290D? if so please change the channel to 1 or 11.

Comment: Hi, there is nothing wrong with the router, my MacBook Pro and my iPad connects just fine. The router I am trying to connect to is SKY7C3D4.

I will do it manually as you said and report back in a few minutes.

Thank you.

Comment: OK, I turned it on and it connected straight away, so I quickly ran that diagnostic program again to see if it reveals anything. As expected it disconnected itself again after 10 minutes. Note this was before I manually changed the country. I've now changed the country code, and it's not connected at all after a restart. It did attempt to connect however, and failed and just said disconnected.

Here is the .txt file I got while it was connected: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7727974/

Comment: Added more instructions.

Comment: Only problem is I can't actually see my router in the list of wireless connections. It's erratic, sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Let's install an updated driver that may fix your issue, the directions are here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472049/after-2nd-update-of-ubuntu-12-04-lts-no-wlan0-again/473190#473190 I have to go out of town and my internet is going to be almost non-existence but I will check back as soon as I can.